# How to save in database a hierarchy class?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I use Java and Hibernate to save my entities in database but it's not working as needed. 
I have a entity Entreprise :

```
@Entity
public class Entreprise{

@Id
private long identifier;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Person>  persons;

...
// getters and setters

}
```

Here the Person entity which a super class of other entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person{

@Id
private long identifier;

@Column
private String name;

...
 // constructors,getter and setter

}
```

And my two subclasses :

```
@Entity
public class Employed extends Person{

 @Column
 private String actualJob;

 // constructors,getter and setter
}


@Entity
public class Unemployed extends Person{

 @Column
 private String lastJob;

// constructors,getter and setter
}
```

Here my method to save the entity in the database :

```
Person person = new Employed();
person.setName("John");
Employed employed = (Employed) person;
employed.setActualJob("electrician");
Entreprise myEntreprise = new Entreprise();
entreprise.getPersons().addPerson(person);
entrepriseDao.save(entreprise);
```

But in the database, the insert was just made in the table Entreprise and Person. Nothing was inserted in the table Employed. I don't know why if someone could explain me, please ?

I try the following code does not also work :

```
Employed employed = new Employed();
employed.setActualJob("electrician");
employed.setName("John");
Entreprise myEntreprise = new Entreprise();
entreprise.getPersons().addPerson(employed);
entrepriseDao.save(entreprise);
```

I don't understand why even if i  use the subclass to set data it does not work.

Here is the ddl

```
Hibernate: insert into Entreprise_Person (Entreprise_identifier, person_identifier) values (?, ?);
```

Comment: Please show the SQL's DDL.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a person reference to the enterprise´s list:

`entreprise.getPersons().addPerson(person);`

Doing that, you add only the person´s data, not the extended employed's data. You should add the  employed object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "YOUR_SUBCLASS_ID_FIELD_THAT_WILL_MATCH_THE_SUPERCLASS_ID_FIELD")` to all subclasses.

The subclasses need identifiers also, this is how they link to their superclass record.

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "identifier")
public class Employed extends Person{

 @Id
 private long identifier;

 @Column
 private String actualJob;

 // constructors,getter and setter
}


@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "identifier")
public class Unemployed extends Person{

 @Id
 private long identifier;

 @Column
 private String lastJob;

// constructors,getter and setter
}
```